# Form Validation Error(Beginner)

Tags: javascript

I am beginning with JavaScript. I just wrote a code for form validation but the checkfields() function is not working. I tried to find the error but couldn't spot it after several attempts. It will be very helpful if someone out there can point out the error.

```html
<html>
<title> Sign-Up </title>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    
    input {
      height: 30px;
      widht: 100px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function valform() {
      var x = document.forms["f2"]["fn"].value;
      var y = document.forms["f2"]["ln"].value;
      var z = document.forms["f2"]["eid"].value;
      var a = document.forms["f2"]["pass"].value;
      var b = document.forms["f2"]["cpass"].value;
      if (x == "" || y == "" || z == "" || a == "" || b == "") {
        alert("Please fill the form completely");
      }

    }

    function checkfields() {
      var p1 = document.forms["f2"]["pass"].value;
      var p2 = document.forms["f2"]["cpass"].value;
      if (p1 != p2) {
        document.getElementByID("message").innerHTML = "Password Doesn't match";
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1> Sign-Up </h1>
    <form name="f2" onsubmit="return checkfields()">
      First-Name: <input type="text" name="fn"> Last-Name :<input type="text" name="ln"><br><br><br> Email-Id:
      <input type="text" name="eid"><br><br><br> Password:
      <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br><br> Confirm-Password
      <input type="password" name="cpass">
      <span id='message'></span>
      <br><br><br>
      <input type="Submit" onclick="valform()" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: error is: `getElementByID` it should be `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

Two things, you need to prevent the default submit event...

`<form name="f2" id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); checkfields()">`

Note.. I also gave your form an ID which will be needed for the next step...

I also removed the onclick from the submit button...

`<input type="Submit"value="Submit">`

I modified your method to return a boolean depending on the validation result

```
function valform() {
      var x = document.forms["f2"]["fn"].value;
      var y = document.forms["f2"]["ln"].value;
      var z = document.forms["f2"]["eid"].value;
      var a = document.forms["f2"]["pass"].value;
      var b = document.forms["f2"]["cpass"].value;
      if (x == "" || y == "" || z == "" || a == "" || b == "") {
        alert("Please fill the form completely");
        return false;
      }

            return true;
    }
```

and I call it within `checkfields` method where upon being success I submit the form using the ID we assigned above...

```
function checkfields() {
  var p1 = document.forms["f2"]["pass"].value;
  var p2 = document.forms["f2"]["cpass"].value;
  if (p1 != p2) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Password Doesn't match";
    return false;
  }

  if(valform()){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  }
}
```

Here's a little [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60h8tpkd/6/) demonstrating the above.

Note: you had one error `getElementByID` should be lower case d (`getElementById`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a js error, `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`

Also I have modified how the validations goes below

You don't need the click handler on the submit, the return is enough on the `onsubmit`.

Onsubmit calls `valform`, and all validation is done within. Since you have a `checkfields` function already, you can simply call it in the validation function.

You also need to return false if the form is incomplete or else it's going to submit anyway. You could make the code a bit cleaner as well by caching `document.forms["f2"]` into a variable

You also had a typo in the css `widht: 100px;`

```js
// saving form into a variable to make it a bit cleaner below
var form_f2 = document.forms["f2"];

function checkfields() {
  var p1 = form_f2["pass"].value;
  var p2 = form_f2["cpass"].value;
  
  if (p1 != p2) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Password Doesn't match";
    return false;
  }
}

function valform() {

  var x = form_f2["fn"].value;
  var y = form_f2["ln"].value;
  var z = form_f2["eid"].value;
  var a = form_f2["pass"].value;
  var b = form_f2["cpass"].value;

  // call to check passwords
  checkfields();

  if (x == "" || y == "" || z == "" || a == "" || b == "") {
    alert("Please fill the form completely");
    // need to return false due to incomplete form
    return false;
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1> Sign-Up </h1>
  <form name="f2" onsubmit="return valform()">
    First-Name: <input type="text" name="fn"> Last-Name :<input type="text" name="ln"><br><br><br> Email-Id:
    <input type="text" name="eid"><br><br><br> Password:
    <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br><br> Confirm-Password
    <input type="password" name="cpass">
    <span id='message'></span>
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</center>
```

You could actually combine the `checkfields` function content into `valform`. I don't see any need for the extra function in the given code

Answer (score 0):

In your `valform()` function you need to pass in the `event` object to prevent submission of the form is validation does not pass with `event.preventDefault()`. Also, `document.getElementByID` should be `document.getElementById`.

```html
<html>
<title> Sign-Up </title>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    
    input {
      height: 30px;
      widht: 100px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function valform(e) {
      var x = document.forms["f2"]["fn"].value;
      var y = document.forms["f2"]["ln"].value;
      var z = document.forms["f2"]["eid"].value;
      var a = document.forms["f2"]["pass"].value;
      var b = document.forms["f2"]["cpass"].value;
      if (x == "" || y == "" || z == "" || a == "" || b == "") {
        alert("Please fill the form completely");
        e.preventDefault();
      }

    }

    function checkfields() {
      var p1 = document.forms["f2"]["pass"].value;
      var p2 = document.forms["f2"]["cpass"].value;
      if (p1 != p2) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Password Doesn't match";
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1> Sign-Up </h1>
    <form name="f2" onsubmit="return checkfields()">
      First-Name: <input type="text" name="fn"> Last-Name :<input type="text" name="ln"><br><br><br> Email-Id:
      <input type="text" name="eid"><br><br><br> Password:
      <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br><br> Confirm-Password
      <input type="password" name="cpass">
      <span id='message'></span>
      <br><br><br>
      <input type="Submit" onclick="valform(event)" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```